# Не удается записать данные введенные пользователем в формате ключ - значение

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет, пишу консольную программу для управления встречами на .NET C# и столкнулся с такой проблемой: не знаю как правильно организовать хранение введенных пользователем даты встречи, времени начала и времени конца. Нужно сделать именно хранение в памяти, не долгосрочное, т.е. без участия БД. Пытался сделать с помощью

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> timeMeeting = new Dictionary <string, List<string>>;
```

Где строка - преобразованная в строку дата, а список - время начала и конца встречи.
Но встаю с вопросом, а как потом изменить, например, время начала встречи или конец или вообще удалить встречу. У кого есть какие мысли по этому поводу, как лучше это организовать?)

Comment: Знаете что такое ООП? Это такой подход к программированию, где все представляется в виде объектов. Вот есть у вас задача, пусть это будет классом, внутри которого будут свойства старт, конец, описание, id и др. Далее класс пользователя, который будет содержать лист класса задач, его имя и другую информацию. Имея такую структуру у вас будет легкий доступ ко всему, что вам надо! Например получить задачу пользователя Вася и изменить значение - `users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x=="Вася").Tasks.LastOrDefault().Start = DateTime.Now();`.

Comment: Создать класс Meeting, прописать нужные поля в него, добавить поле id, хранить по вкусу... например в `List<Meeting>`. В вашем случае сложно добавлять новые поля в сущность. А этот паттерн ("хранилище") очень широко распространён.